# Excel VBA modifying word doc from excel - collection member error

Tags: vba, excel

Running below code is bringing up "requested member of the collection does not exist"  All searches have not produced an solution.

```
Sub WordTemplate()


Dim objWordapp As Object
Set objWordapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
fileStr = "\\int.chc.concepts.co.nz\users\CBotting\Documents\VBA programming\SD Basic Template.docx"

objWordapp.Documents.Open FileName:=fileStr
With objWordapp.Selection.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
    If .Range.Text <> vbCr Then
        MsgBox .Range.Text
    Else
        MsgBox "Header is empty"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

I have tried many different variations of addressing the header object

Comment: did you add a reference to the _Microsoft Word Object Library_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't the late binding.  The problem was that the VBA doesn't know the value of `wdHeaderFooterPrimary` without a reference to the Microsoft Word xx.x Object Library.  I tell the VBA the value of wdHeaderFooterPrimary then your code would work without the reference to the Word library set.

```
Sub WordTemplate()
    Const wdHeaderFooterPrimary = 1

    Dim objWordapp As Object
    Set objWordapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    fileStr = "\\int.chc.concepts.co.nz\users\CBotting\Documents\VBA programming\SD Basic Template.docx"

    objWordapp.Documents.Open Filename:=fileStr
    With objWordapp.Selection.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
        If .Range.Text <> vbCr Then
            MsgBox .Range.Text
        Else
            MsgBox "Header is empty"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the actual issue.  Good not to have to reference the library.  Great answer

Comment: Thanks for the Check!  A great thing about using CreateObject is that it doesn't matter what version of the library the user has on his machine.

Answer (score 0):

Am running early binding method so needed to set in the VBA Tools menu the Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library.  Now works